# An error occurred while trying to share D. Incorrect function.

Tags: windows, networking, sharing

OK, at first I thought it was a Norton 360 problem so I deleted Norton 360. The Windows firewall is no longer being controlled by it.

Windows firewall is turned off, it's a public location, printer and file sharing is turned on, discovery is on, I reloaded the default settings for the firewall, the owner is administrator which my login is set for. Didn't matter if the Windows firewall was turned on or off, I still got the error message above.

I used to have D shared but took it off. Now when I try to create the share I get the error message above.

I have another Win 7 Pro computer with the same settings as above and I can share everything just fine.

Any ideas on how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found something nice that fixed my problem...

See solution on: [Firewall and sharing folders](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/78fbca5c-41ad-4fa6-8ccd-f52045333fdd/windows-7-firewall-fails-to-restore-default-policy-error-3?forum=w7itprosecurity&prof=required)

I did what he recommend:

- export firewall polices from a Windows 7 computer that does not have this problem.  (Option on the right most panel of the 3 panel screen for Windows Firewall - advanced)
- Copy the .wfw file you exported to your bad firewall computer.
- Use the "import Policy" option in Windows Firewall to replace the firewall policy on the bad computer.

  It fixed my issue.  Firewall is working - so are home groups.