# Unable to share folder - Error: 'Incorrect function'

Tags: windows, directory, firewall, sharing

I'm unable to share any folders.
I'm always getting the following error:

An error occurred while trying to share [your folder]. Incorrect function. The shared resource was not created at this time.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728665/an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-share-d-incorrect-function

Comment: Yes and no. I took 1 full day to find the article you mention because the problem described was not described the same as what I had. When somebody has a problem, they usually enter the "Error" message box text and hope to find the information. If they do that, they will never find the article you mention. Moreover, the guy did not yet mention that it is the appropriate answer and by the way leaves the answer as probably wrong !

Comment: To be a dup, the question should be the same (at least to me) !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I applied following solution with success :
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/78fbca5c-41ad-4fa6-8ccd-f52045333fdd/windows-7-firewall-fails-to-restore-default-policy-error-3?forum=w7itprosecurity&prof=required

Text:

Ok - I think I have an answer.  Looks like the Firewall polices are corrupted in some weird way.  I found a recommendation:

- export firewall polices from a Windows 7 computer that does not have this problem.  (Option on the right most panel of the 3 panel screen for Windows Firewall)
- Copy the .wfw file you exported to your bad firewall computer.
- Use the "import Policy" option in Windows Firewall to replace the firewall policy on the bad computer.

  It fixed my issue.  Firewall is working and shared folders also.

Hope it helps !
Eric

Answer (score 4):

I was able to work around this error by stopping the "windows firewall" service for few short seconds, and then enabling it again once the sharing changes were applied/accepted.